# Update Selected Column using ORDER BY or base on Higher Value of Other Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to make a SQL script or statement which has a function of updating the column but it only update the high OnlineTime.

- DatabaseName: Ranking
- Table: ChaInfo
- Columns: UserNum, CharacterName,OnlineTime,Points

Lets say there are 3 column that has the same UserNum but different OnlineTime Record, Then What I want to happen is UPDATE the POINTS of the one that has a highest OnlineTime.

Sample code but its not working:

```
UPDATE ChaInfo
SET Points = Points + 10
SELECT TOP 1 UserNum
WHERE UserNum = 1 
ORDER BY OnlineTime DESC
```

Please help me to fix this code.Thanks.

Comment: please show sample data and expected result in text and not as image

Comment: You did not understand the concept of Order BY! You can use order by to ORDER the result of your query and you can not use it on a Update.

Comment: Please don't use a image as Data or Result when you ask a question. The Sample data and expected result might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update row with UserNum=1 and highest onlineTime , try this:

```
UPDATE chainfo
SET points = points + 10
WHERE usernum =1
and onlinetime=(select max(onlinetime)
               from chainfo
               where usernum =1)
```

Comment: WOW This Codes Works... Thank You! & GOD BLESS :)

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use an updatable CTE, which requires only a single scan of the table**

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (1)  -- add WITH TIES for tied rows
      points
    FROM chainfo
    WHERE usernum = 1
    ORDER BY onlinetime DESC
)
UPDATE cte
SET points += 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` keyword is used to sort the result-set in ascending or descending order.

Use `ORDER BY` in UPDATE statement makes no sense. If if was supposed to work, you could update your data order by a column not as you want to update ONLY HIGH SCORE ONLINE TIME.

Answer (score 0):

How about using MAX to get highest online time instead of ORDER BY:

```
UPDATE a SET
    a.points = a.points + 10
FROM ChaInfo AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userNum, MAX(onlineTime) AS onlineTime FROM ChaInfo GROUP BY userNum
) AS b
ON a.userNum = b.userNum AND a.onlineTime = b.onlineTime
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE chainfo
SET points = points + 10
WHERE usernum IN (SELECT usernum 
                  FROM chainfo 
                  WHERE usernum = 1
                  ORDER BY onlinetime DESC)
```

You can try this

Comment: I already tried your query but i got an error it say "The ORDER BY clause in invalid in views, inline functions, derived table,subqueries blah blah blah..." Also i tried to put TOP 1 , query is working but it SET value to all that have sa 1 UserNum.

Comment: Just take the order by out... its not like it does anything.

Comment: If i remove ORDER BY the result was all column that has same UserNum has gain value of 10, it should be choose one only base on higher value on OnlineTime . Thanks

Comment: You can use order by to ORDER the result of your query and you can not use it on a Update.  The code you wrote is completely redundant.

Comment: Hmmmm so there is no alternative for ORDER BY that could work with UPDATE Statement?. Thanks.